# Spring-batch metadata tables in different schema

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a datasource that connects to an Oracle database in my application. Is it possible to access to another schema that includes the Spring-batch metadata tables through this datasource? The user of this datasource has all rights to access to the other schema.

I have already tried "tablePrefix" attribute of the JobRepository such as "Schema.batch_". But it does not work. Briefly, I search for the way to tell the Spring-batch to access to the metadata tables like "select ....from Schema.batch_.." not "select ...from batch_...".

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: In fact, I am not getting an error. But I see that Spring Batch tries to query with tables names without any schema prefix, even I define the tablePrefix property as "schema.batch_".

Answer (score 17):

I faced the same issue since I want to keep application tables in one schema and batch tables in a separate one (using postgres).

`tablePrefix` didn't work for me either (I tried different cases - none of it solves the issue).

So finally I deciced to configure a separate DataSource for Spring Batch pointing to a `batch` schema. Here is how I did it.

In **application.properties** file I have standard props like `spring.datasource.*` which is used for the application as a primary datasource.

And props like `spring.batch.datasource.*` is non-standard and is a secondary datasource used only in the code provided below.

Here is example of **application.properties** file:

```
spring.datasource.url=APP_DB_CONNECTION_URL
spring.datasource.username=APP_DB_USER
spring.datasource.password=APP_DB_PASS

spring.batch.datasource.url=BATCH_DB_CONNECTION_URL
spring.batch.datasource.username=BATCH_DB_USER
spring.batch.datasource.password=BATCH_DB_PASS
```

Then in **BatchConfiguration.java** which is a part of app sources I added `getBatchDataSource` method which reads `spring.batch.datasource.*` properties:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.batch.datasource")
  public DataSource getBatchDataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  ...

}
```

This makes Spring Batch to use a separate data source.

Now important thing is to setup `spring.batch.datasource.*` correctly:

> For Postgres 9.4 you can specify schema in the connection URL using `currentSchema` parameter: `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db?currentSchema=batch`
>
> For Postgres before 9.4 you can specify schema in the connection URL using `searchpath` parameter: `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db?searchpath=batch`
>
> Or you can create a separate postgres user/role for `batch` schema and setup `search_path` for that user: `ALTER USER BATCH_DB_USER SET search_path to 'batch';`
>
> In Oracle each user has their own schema (as far as i know) and no way to set schema in the connection URL like for postgres (I may be wrong): `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/sid`
>
> So you need to create a separate user for `batch` schema in Oracle. Another way is to use `spring.batch.datasource.validation-query=ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=batch` (I didn't try this)

So in this way Spring Batch uses a separate datasource configured to use dedicated `batch` schema. Batch queries still look like `select ...from batch_...` however it runs against `batch` schema. And application is using regular datasource pointing to an application dedicated schema `app`.

This solution was tested using Spring Boot v1.2.5.RELEASE and Postgres 9.4.1

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you alextunick. I have already solved the problem with the way you described. I used separate data sources. But It would be better if I did not have to define another data source and use the same datasource with granting the other schema.

Comment: Any solution for above problem other than two datasources ? I have same requirement I want to have metadatatables in different schema and also I actually dont want  spring batch to create tables rather I have to create that upfront. I use latest sprint boot(2.x) .

Comment: I found a solution https://better-coding.com/spring-batch-metadata-tables-in-different-database-schema/

Comment: @user3444718 - I also the need the solution around your requirement. Were u able to solve this ?

Comment: setting spring.batch.tableprefix=<yourschema>.batch_ should solve problem

Comment: @alex - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086749/spring-batch-unable-to-create-metadata-tables-on-postgres-and-load-actual-data ?

Comment: `datasource.jdbc-url` worked for me instead of `datasource.url`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `spring.batch.table-prefix=<yourschema>.batch_` did not work for me and I could not immediately configure the second datasource, I took a look at the actual table generation done by Spring Batch.

The [sql-Script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.2.2.RELEASE/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql) which generates the tables is static (at least in the release 4.2.2 and for Postgresql).
Therefore it is no wonder that `spring.batch.table-prefix` does not work. At least in my case as the tables do not yet exist in the database.

To fix it I copied `schema-postgresql.sql` to my resource folder and modified it to my needs (creating the schema and referencing it explicitly).

```
CREATE SCHEMA SPRING_BATCH;

CREATE TABLE SPRING_BATCH.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    -- and so on
```

In my `application.properties` I added:

```
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.table-prefix=SPRING_BATCH.BATCH_
spring.batch.schema=classpath:db/create_spring_batch_tables.sql
```